# Make an onEdit script read other columns to determine where to send data based on edits

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script currently works, but I would like to add the ability to read data in Column A of Sheet1 (usernames) so that the row is moved to the corresponding sheet. For instance, if "Jim" is the username listed in Column A, the script will send the row to "Jim's" Sheet. There will be 9 different users on this sheet and I would like to move away from everyone viewing the "Master" tab so to speak.

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {

    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @LioraHaydont Hi Liora! Apologies, I should've noted that. I tried adding an additional r.getValue() variable in the "if" statement but I'm guessing that doesn't work because those variables are edit triggers. I'm unsure how to request that the script read column A values first.

Comment: s.getRange(event.range.rowStart, 1).getValue() ?

Comment: @JPV Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. The script now works perfectly but only for new entries beyond what is pre-existing in the Sheet. I am wondering if I need to change `var row = r.getRow();` and `s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns)` in order to allow the script to edit pre-existing content.